# Unable to Connect to remote Apache-Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, ssh

I'm new to [apache-spark](https://spark.apache.org/) and I'm experiencing some issues while trying to connect from my local machine to a remote server which contains a Spark working instance.

I successfully managed to connect vis SSH tunnel to that server using [JSCH](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) but I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> scala.Predef$.$scope()Lscala/xml/TopScope$;   at
> org.apache.spark.ui.jobs.AllJobsPage.(AllJobsPage.scala:39)     at
> org.apache.spark.ui.jobs.JobsTab.(JobsTab.scala:38)     at
> org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI.initialize(SparkUI.scala:65)  at
> org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI.(SparkUI.scala:82)  at
> org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI$.create(SparkUI.scala:220)    at
> org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI$.createLiveUI(SparkUI.scala:162)  at
> org.apache.spark.SparkContext.(SparkContext.scala:452)  at
> server.Server$.main(Server.scala:45)  at
> server.Server.main(Server.scala)

When trying to connect to Spark.

This is my scala code

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Test").setMaster("spark://xx.xxx.xxx.x:7077")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)).count()
println(rdd)
```

Where line `45` highlighted at `(Server.scala:45)` in the error is the one with `new SparkContext(conf)`.

Both on local and remote machine I'm using `scala ~ 2.11.6`. On my local `pom.xml` file I imported `scala : 2.11.6`, `spark-core_2.10` and `spark-sql_2.10` both `~2.1.1`. On my server I installed `spark ~ 2.1.1`. ON the server I also managed to setup the `master` as the local machine by editing `conf/spark-env.sh`.

Of course, I managed to test server's spark and It works just fine.

**What Am I doing wrong?**

Comment: How are you trying to connect? Are you submitting a job with `spark-submit` or running a `spark-shell`?

Comment: If you mean on the server, I run my test using `spark-shell`.

Comment: You don't need to create a new `SparkContext` in the `spark-shell`, there is one ready for you as soon as you get to the prompt, it's name is `sc`.

Comment: Do you mean that I do not Need to create a new SparkContext since I'm already connected to the server in ssh?

Comment: Ofc the code I put relies on my machine, on Intellij Idea. I'm not trying ti create a new context on server's spark-shell.

Comment: No. First, you connect to the remote node on your cluster with `ssh`, then you open `spark-shell`. Within `spark-shell`, a `SparkContext` has already been created for you. You can access it with its name, `sc`, without the need to create a new one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147921/discussion-between-stefanobaghino-and-andream16).

Comment: Give me some minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the docs of setMaster:

> The master URL to connect to, such as "local" to run locally with one thread, "local[4]" to
>      run locally with 4 cores, or "spark://master:7077" to run on a Spark standalone cluster.

If you run it from the spark cluster (as I understand you are), you should use `local[n]`