# Unable to connect to remote Spark Master - ROR TransportRequestHandler: Error while invoking RpcHandler#receive() for one-way message

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44823913/unable-to-connect-to-remote-apache-spark) some time ago but it came out that I was using my local resources instead of remote's ones.

I have a remote machine configured with `spark : 2.1.1`, `cassandra : 3.0.9` and `scala : 2.11.6`.

Cassandra is configured at `localhost:9032` and spark master at `localhost:7077`.

Spark master is set to `127.0.0.1` and its port to `7077`.

> I'm able to connect to cassandra remotely but unable to do the same
>   thing with spark.

When connecting to the remote spark master, I get the following error:

> ERROR TransportRequestHandler: Error while invoking RpcHandler#receive() for one-way message.

Here are my settings via code

```
val configuration = new SparkConf(true)
                        .setAppName("myApp")
                        .setMaster("spark://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:7077")
                        .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "xx.xxx.xxx.xxx")
                        .set("spark.cassandra.connection.port", 9042)
                        .set("spark.cassandra.input.consistency.level","ONE")
                        .set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
val sparkSession = SparkSession
                   .builder()
                   .appName("myAppEx")
                   .config(configuration)
                   .enableHiveSupport()
                   .getOrCreate()
```

I don't understand why cassandra works just fine and spark does not.

**What's causing this? How can I solve?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I answer to this question in order to help other people who are struggling with this problem.

It came out that it was caused by a mismatch between [Intellij Idea](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)'s scala version and server's one.

Server had `scala ~ 2.11.6` while the IDE was using `scala ~ 2.11.8`.

In order to make sure of using the very same version, it was necessary to change IDE's scala version by doing the following steps:

**File > Project Structure > + > Scala SDK > Find and select server's scala Version > Download it if you haven't it already installed > Ok > Apply > Ok**

Answer (score 1):

Could this be a typo? The errormessage reports 8990, in your connect config you have port 8090 for spark.

Comment: There was a typo but due to the fact that I miscopied one port. Of course the problem persists. Anyways I fixed my question, thanks.

Comment: What I just had is differing spark versions (or so I assume), which led to connection errors, broken pipes.
On the spark side, I could see this in the logs, on the spark-client side, I could not see a sensible message.
Also a problem I had was, that spark was not fully up - start-all.sh was the way to go there.